# Using function's context versus passing parameters to a function

Tags: javascript

I want to know how using `this` keyword within a function by passing the context is better than passing a parameter to a function.

for Example:

```
var dog = {
    name: 'puppy'
};

function foo(obj) {
    console.log(obj.name);
}

foo(dog); // puppy
```

I realized that I have been following the above pattern way to much in my code. Although I haven't hit that stage where its limitations are obvious. I want to know how using `this` is more elegant. That is, using the below pattern instead:

```
function foo(){
    console.log(this.name);
}

foo.call(dog); //puppy
```

Comment: *I realized that I have been following the above pattern way too much in my code.* This is a basic pattern--passing a parameter to a function--that has been used in JS since the dawn of history.

Comment: I know that but claims have been made that following the latter practice promotes cleaner APIs, hence the question....

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what the function will serve and what you're trying to accomplish.

But to be frank, the best use-case for using context in your simple example would be to **add the fonction to the `dog` object**, that way, you avoid having to set the context each time.

```js
var dog = {
  name: 'puppy',
  printName: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};

dog.printName();
```

Or making a class from the `dog` object.

```js
var Dog = function(name) {
  this._name = name;
};

Dog.prototype = {
  constructor: Dog,
  getName: function() {
    return this._name
  },
  printToConsole: function() {
    console.log("Dog named", this.getName());
  }
};

var myDog = new Dog("puppy");

myDog.printToConsole();
```

If function `foo` is going to be a free function, having to set the context each time makes no sense. Passing a parameter is the way to go.

Using `.call`, `.apply` or `.bind` makes sense when dealing with callbacks which happen to be methods from other objects.

Also, `foo.call(dog);` or `foo(dog)` is only useful if the object has a property named `name`, restricting its use to the `dog` object.

It could receive the `name` directly:

```
function foo(name) {
    console.log(name);
}
foo(dog.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how using this keyword within a function by passing the context is better than passing a parameter to a function.

This is a very broad question

The short and equally broad answer is that using `this.property` makes it possible to construct a function that uses the values of the object of the function's *callsite*.

Why is that smart? Because you then can let it do the same work again and again without having *manually* to pass in arguments reflecting the different contexts in which you are using the function.

---

You can use `.call`, `.apply` and `.bind` to manually set the context of `this`. This is useful when you cannot rely on the callsite of a function and essentially lets you pass in an "unlimited" number of arguments by just setting the context.

Comment: Both `foo.call(dog)` and `foo(dog)` needs you to pass `dog` equally.

Comment: Agreed and therefore also more similar to passing arguments. Understanding `this` should not begin with understanding `.call`, `.apply` and .`bind`

Comment: `essentially lets you pass in an "unlimited" number of arguments by just setting the context`... Arguments already let you do that without the extra step. That's kind of the essence of arguments.